# Glib type testing macros cause segfault when passed a GSList

Tags: c, gtk, segmentation-fault, glib

Passing a `GSList` to a Glib macro (Like `G_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME()`, `GTK_IS_WIDGET()` etc) causes a segmentation fault.

This is a problem as my program has to process a list of GObjects and can't test for GSLists... In addition, merely performing a test on a GSList causes a segfault so it can't even get to an else block.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    g_type_init();
    GtkWidget * widget;

    GSList * gslist = NULL;
    gslist = g_slist_append(gslist,widget);

    GHashTable * table = g_hash_table_new(NULL,NULL);
    g_hash_table_insert(table, (gchar *) "key", (char *) "value");
    g_hash_table_insert(table, (gchar *) "slist", gslist);

    if(GTK_IS_WIDGET(g_hash_table_lookup(table,"slist"))){}
}
```

Segfault occurs in `g_type_check_instance_is_a () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0`, removing GTK_IS_WIDGET program runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GSList`is not a `GObject` i.e. it does not provide the machinery necessary for the type-check macros to work, which results in the crash you observe. If you really need such functionality, you might need to create a wrapper (based on `GObject`) for your lists.

Unfortunately, you cannot test for the type of value in your hash table; the type-checking macros used by `GObject` and GTK actually require a dedicated support in the value being pointed to, i.e., you have to positively know, that the value is something, which uses the `GObject` machinery before you can use the macros in the first place. The results are simply undefined, if they are applied to pointers to anything but `GObject`-derived types, and more often than not will cause crashes.

Note, BTW., that this problem arises with the string values (`char*`) and other values as well. (Why do you cast `"value"` to `char*`?)

If you really need to work with a generic hash table like stated in your example, you will have to create a wrapper of some kind; either directly derive it from `GObject` or try something minimal like

```
typedef struct {
     int type_code;
     union {
         int ival;
         char* str;
         GObject* obj;
         GSList* list;
     } value;
} Cell;

typedef enum {
     INTEGER, STRING, OBJECT, LIST
} CellType;

Cell* 
allocate_int_cell(int value)
{
    ...
}
```

Things are unfortunately even more complicated than this, because you will also have to manage the destruction of your values when they are removed from the hash table (or if the hash table itself is destroyed).

Comment: I don't need any functionality such as that, I just need it not to segfault when it's passed. Is it possible to test if something is a GObject without causing a segfault? That would fix my problem.

Comment: But the problem isn't in the hash table, it's the GSList that's causing the problem. I think it might be possible to attempt to get the data variable from the `GSList` struct and use that to determine it's type. (Or at least determine that it shouldn't be passed to type-checks)

Comment: Empty `GSList`s are just NULL pointers - how would you get a data variable from those?

Comment: @JV I did. The problem is, that you cannot be sure what the type of value is you are reading from the table: it might be (according to the example) a string ("char*"), it might be a GSList, basically: it might be anything. How do you distinguish between a GObject*, a GSList* and a char* at pointer level? (And when reading the value, all you have is a pointer to some memory location, nothing else).

Comment: This is my problem: I need to somehow determine the difference

Comment: Yep. Hence my proposal to either use a tagged value type ("Cell") or go with a `GObject`-based wrapper right from the start; the latter might prove worthwhile in the long run, but the former will be faster to implement ad-hoc, I guess.

Comment: Oh screw it I'll figure out a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're basically doing is:

```
if (GTK_IS_WIDGET(gslist))
```

As Dirk already said, this won't work as GSList is not a GObject. This is the data *inside* the GList that you should check, not the GSList itself.

Comment: Whenever I try to access `itemsinsidehashtable->data` to check, it doesn't work because the compiler doesn't expect it to be a GSList (Rightly so as most are GtkWidgets)

Comment: What you're trying to do is extremely unclear. The observed comportment is normal. GTK_IS_WIDGET is made to assert if the var is not a widget, which a GSList is obviously not. How are you trying to check `itemsinsidehashtable->data`, and which data did you insert in it?